# Unity error: type "x" exist in both 'A' and 'B'

Tags: unity, c#

I just opened a project made in unity version 2018.1.1f into Unity version 2020.1.1f
I know opening the older projects is not supported by Unity but it opened fine.

The only problem is that it is giving an error which looks like this-[image]

What I tried:

1. checking the script `onetizationPlatform.cs` to ensure nothing is wrong in it
2. checked that there's no two files with same name `unitylifecyclemanager`
3. doing point 2 with `unityengine.advertisement.editor`
4. deleting `unityengine.advertisement.editor` which caused another error so I had to restore it back

Comment: While I haven't experienced this particular error myself, I have resolved similar errors after updates by checking the package manager and making sure all packages are up-to-date.

Comment: Is it possible `UnityEngine.Advertisements.Editor` used to be a standalone package and is now part of `UnityEngine.Advertisements`? (which would then conflict with the one still in your project). Since the latter has a higher version than the more specific one..?

Comment: I've had this problem before with some other package, and it was caused because I had installed package X manually, but it was also a dependency of some other package. So I had two versions of the same package. I solved it by removing the manually installed package and using the one that was the dependency.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't installed any package manually and also made sure that all of my packages are up to date

Comment: @D.Kallan even if that's the case,what is the way to fix it?

Comment: You could check which one is newer, I don't think that's automatically the higher version one, and remove that one. Backup the project just in case. Removing one of the packages should resolve this conflict. If it is too difficult to figure out which one is newer, you can always make 2 copies of the project and remove 1 in each... its not optimal but its something to try.

Comment: @Rajjaiswal Edit: I just googled and found this one: feels similar but did you see it? Maybe it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61377566/the-type-advertisement-exists-in-both-unityengine-advertisements-editor. They talk about having a store asset for Monetization which clashes with the Ads from Unity Services and that deleting the store asset while importing monetization from the package manager has solved it for some. Otherwise it's back to my previous comment, figuring out where the files duplicate and removing that package/thing.

Comment: @D.Kallan Thanks mate! The problem is quite similar to mine,and maybe doing this will fix it. I'll update you about whatever happens

Comment: Hii,i tried your method and it kinda works. I am able to remove advertisement from package manager which removes the error but the ads stopped working. Also i am unable to remove unity monetization package from the project because it only gives option to install it eventhough it is already installed

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by first removing unity advertisements from package manager and then deleting every single advertisement or monetization related file from my project

After that I reinstalled unity advertisement from package manager which first gave 2-3 errors which were clearable and then everything started working nicely.